# Accessing non-allocated sectors of hard disk in C

Tags: c, macos, hard-drive, diskspace

I am using OSX Yosemite.  I recently cleaned a hard drive by writing a little C program that printed chars to a giant file on the disk.  I deleted the file and now I would like to try and read the disk sectors that were written to.  The challenge is that I'm trying to access disk that is no longer allocated.

QUESTION : How do I access unallocated areas of disk space in C?

For instance the following is unable to access the disk.  It exits due to `f == NULL`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 1000

int main(void)
{
    FILE * f = fopen("/dev/disk3s1", "r");
    char c[N];
    unsigned int numread = 0;

    if(f == NULL)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR!!! f did not open\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   

    numread = fread(c, sizeof(char), N, f); 
    printf("numread = %u\n", numread);
    printf("%s", c); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seg-fault, I corrected the above posting.  I meant to say it exits due to f == NULL

Comment: "unable to access" - so the disc is in another room? It is locked away? The cable is broken? It does not rotate? The controller is broken? The driver doesn't work? ...

Comment: Try `perror("ERROR!!! f did not open");` and see what it tells you.

Comment: Insufficient permission, perhaps? Access of pretty much everything in `/dev/*` is reserved for superuser...

Comment: How about reading the error details ...?

Comment: Are you sure that it segfaults? Where? Only possible cause is that `c` is not guaranteed to be NUL-terminated, but I find that unlikely that there will be no NUL. Saw your update, but you will still have to address that eventually if you get by the `fopen`. Normally when `fopen` fails you should be able to use `perror` to get infy why `fopen` failed. I'd guess that you don't have permissions to open `/dev/disk3s1`.

Comment: So, I ran `sudo ./a.out` with the compiled code.  It still is unable to open the disk.  Obvioulsy, I'm not sure if this code is the appropriate manner to do this task.

Comment: Yeah people want to know what the error is.  `ENOENT` or  `EPERM` - it matters.  I also worry for the rest of your data if this is how you intend to treat your disk.

Comment: How would I get those?

Comment: print out `errno` or use `strerror()`.

Comment: `a.out` returns errno as 13.  If I run `sudo ./a.out` it is 16

Comment: Permission Denied and Device Busy.  You need to do some reading before proceeding as you are out of your depth.

Comment: you might want to read: `http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/misc/article.php/c5765/ReadingWriting-Disk-Sectors-Absolute-Disk-ReadWrite.htm` as it discusses `raw` disk I/O (under windows) but should give you a basis to start from.